# A bug with NSMutableArray of NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

```
NSString *str = @"1 2 3 4 5";
NSMutableArray *strArray = [[[str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] mutableCopy] autorelease];
[strArray removeObjectAtIndex:3];
[strArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

At the end of this code I expect that array contains @"2", @"3", @"5".

But it contains 0x00000, @"2", @"3".

How to fix it? Numbers are for example only, there could be various strings of various length separated with spaces.

**UPDATED**

It is strange, but it really writes 2, 3, 5 into console.

But here is the same array in debug window:

[image]

Comment: This is really strange. I don't see any problem with your code.

Comment: have used your code only, and its working fine for me

Comment: I have updated the alternative of yours. Please try :)

Comment: The "Debugger Variables View" is just *buggy* sometimes, I have seen more reports like that. Use "po strArray" in the "Debugger Console", or NSLog() in your source code to get reliable results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I think is happening.  What you have is, if anything, a bug in the debugger.

Let's assume for the moment that `NSMutableArray` is represented by a normal C array internally.  The naive implementation of `-removeObjectAtIndex:` would shuffle up all the objects after the one you want to remove into the previous slot in the array.  This has O(n) complexity, where n is the number of objects in the array.

An optimisation might be to associate a "base index" with the array which will be subtracted from the index supplied to any method that takes an index as a parameter.  That way, `[foo removeObjectAtIndex: 0]` can be implemented by simply assigning nil to the first element and bumping the base index for constant time complexity.

I'm sure the real implementation is more complex than that, but the above just serves to illustrate the idea.

If the debugger doesn't know about this, it would display the underlying C array exactly as it does in the screen cap your question.  The point is that you can't really trust the debugger on anything where it can't be expected to know the internals of the object.  Printing the description to the console is a much more reliable method of examining the object - as long as `-description` has a helpful implementation.

Comment: I have disabled an optimizatization in debug mode. And it looks impossible to assign nil to an element of array in objective-c

Comment: Correct, but the internal implementation of the array is doing it, not you.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why your code is not working its working fine for me, also tried the same in other way below :-

```
NSString *str = @"1 2 3 4 5";
NSArray *arr1= [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSMutableArray *strArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arr1];
[strArray removeObjectAtIndex:3];
[strArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@",strArray);

Output:-

2
3
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using ARC? I have tested that code using ARC and it works. So, can you explain it a little bit more what you are trying to do? (I could't added it as comment)

Comment: Because I can't simply take a half-ready project and convert it to ARC because of this bug only.

Comment: This answer should really be a comment on the question.

Comment: JeremyP, as I wrote, I couldn't add that as comment because when I posted, I didn't have enough points to put comments.

Answer (score 0):

remove your autorelease! Fine working for me!

```
NSString *str = @"1 2 3 4 5";
    NSMutableArray *strArray = [[str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] mutableCopy];
    [strArray removeObjectAtIndex:3];
    [strArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"strArray = %@", strArray);
```

2013-10-16 14:29:35.537 Notes[566:c07] strArray = (
    2,
    3,
    5
)